# Why does dropdown menu always mess my css layout?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

Every time I include a dropdown menu, my css layout mess up. Can someone explain to me why and how to fix it?

Here is my code:

```
            <asp:Label ID="projnamelbl" runat="server" CssClass="editlabels" Text="Project                  Name"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="projnametxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />

        <asp:Label ID="paymentlbl" runat="server" CssClass="editlabels" Text="Payment  Type:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="paymentype" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Cash" Value="cash"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Intallments" Value="installments"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList><br />

        <asp:Label ID="projsumlbl" CssClass="editlabels" runat="server" Text="Project  Sum:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="projsumtxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
```

CSS:

```
   .editlabels {
   float:left;
   width:150px;
   margin-right:0.2em;
   padding-top:0.4em;
   padding-left:20px;
   text-align:left;
   font-weight:bold;
   }
```

Anything that goes after the dropdown menu goes to the right for some reason.

Comment: Because you need to use `position: absolute;`

Answer (score 1):

Only if you remove your margin and padding things would automatically fall in place.

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly. Could you explain why please?

Comment: I would simply say that how you designed it. What you can do is remove <br \> tags and see how the page is rendered. What you would see is all labels one after another followed by controls in a single line. This what float:left would do. Now if you wanted to get everything correctly in a line then I would have asked you to set float:left for text boxes as well. But you wanted each label-control combination one followed by other, that's why I asked you to remove padding and margin since these were hindering the normal line break by <br> tag. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `position: relative` on the main container then on any sub ones use `position: absolute`